# No-Javascript editable text region that saves

Tags: html, css, text, contenteditable

I want to create an editable text region that will stay after you reload a page, (creating a notes section) but for the project I am working on I am limited to only HTML and CSS.

I have tried these, but when I reopen the page the text reverts back to the filler text.

```
.readwrite {
  -moz-user-modify: read-write;
  -webkit-user-modify: read-write;
}

<div class="readwrite" contenteditable="true">
 text to be edited
</div>
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: This can't be done using only `HTML` and `CSS`. You either use a programming language to save you settings somewhere or make use of `AJAX` to create a webpage which dynamically and partially loads your page.

Comment: @Tom — Ajax isn't an alternative to using a programming language, it is something you do with one.

Comment: @Quentin Well, not exactly as you can load an XML "part" in a page using `AJAX`. So no need for a programming language.

Comment: @Tom — Ajax is a buzzword meaning "To make an HTTP request using **JavaScript** in a webpage without leaving the page". So yes, there is a need for a programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to save content between page loads is to use a programming language to save it somewhere. What you want is not achievable with just HTML and CSS.